# My App is rejected while I used UINavigationBar

Tags: cocoa, uinavigationbar

My app is rejected as email by Apple due to following code, Apple declared `showButtonWithLeftTitle` as private API method so any help please..

```
nav = [[UINavigationBar alloc] 
initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 433.0f-rotatecheck, 320.0f, 48.0f)];

[nav showButtonsWithLeftTitle: @"<<" 
    rightTitle: @">>" leftBack: NO];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to create a navigation bar by yourself? Perhaps it's a better idea for you to create an `UINavigationController` and set the left and right buttons of the navigationItem of the view controller on its navigation stack. If you really just want the navigation bar, create an `UINavigationItem` (with left and right buttons set) and push it onto the navigation stack of your navigation bar (`pushNavigationItem:animated:`). If you need more buttons than just a left and right one, use `UIToolbar`.